logrotate not working as per configuration provided
I am working on a java application running in Ubuntu Server (16.04) which copies log files from certain folders and consolidate then when user closes the session.
In ubuntu server rsyslog filters and keeps generating logs from different devices (external) and stores logs in a folder.
After the files copied by java application I need to rotate the logs. For that I am planning to use logrotate program. I created a config to rotate this files once a session is closed (user triggers this by closing the session in application).
The files created in the folder (/media/content/persist/log/external/) as below:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 syslog syslog  283 Jul  1 20:49 192.168.10.100-syslog.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 syslog syslog  24K Jul  1 21:25 192.168.10.11-syslog.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 syslog syslog 8.6K Jul  1 21:25 192.168.10.10-syslog.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 syslog syslog 439K Jul  1 21:40 192.168.10.12-syslog.log

Log rotate config: **File: rsyslog-fc-rotate.conf **
/media/content/persist/log/external/*-syslog.log
{  
  rotate 4 
  maxsize 5M
  compress  
  missingok
  notifempty 
  postrotate
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
  endscript
}

When I run logrotate manually I am getting the result below without any rotation is being happend
> logrotate -f -d -v rsyslog-fc-rotate.conf 
reading config file rsyslog-fc-rotate.conf

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /media/content/persist/log/external/*-syslog.log
 forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 5242880 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
considering log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.10-syslog.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.11-syslog.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.12-syslog.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20240701'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.4.gz to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.5.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.3.gz to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.4.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.2.gz to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.3.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.1.gz to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.2.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.0.gz to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.1.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 0), 
renaming /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log to /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.1
running postrotate script
running script with arg /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log: "
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
removing old log /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.5.gz
error: error opening /media/content/persist/log/external/192.168.10.100-syslog.log.5.gz: No such file or directory

This message is repeating for all the files and no rotation is happening. Not sure why it is failing.
In my application with this config, for every session close the files needs to be rotated. This logrorate call will be coming from a java service.

Ubuntu 16.04 - added it to the question also

You understand that 16.04 is pretty much out of support now?

Yes. But it's our platform for thousands of servers and no other option.. :)

That's an even more important reason to be moving away from it to a supported system. Can you afford for your thousands of servers to be impacted by a critical issue?

This is to be expected as you're using the -d flag. The documentation (see man logrotate) writes,

-d, --debug Turn on debug mode, which means that no changes are made to the  logs and  the logrotate state file is not updated.  Only debug messages are printed


Oh my bad. Didn't know this flag does this. Thanks. Now it is working as expected.
